# How do I get zxing working with my iPhone project?

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, zxing

I am trying to use ZXingWidget with an iPhone project I am working on, and I followed the instructions in the readme and I only got one error message.

in one of the c++ header files was this command:

```
#include <iostream>
```

my build failed because iostream was not found.

I am not familiar with c++, so I am not sure where it is pulling iostream from.  I am guessing it is a c++ library or something of that nature.  Anybody know how I can fix this, or what I might be doing wrong?  Any input, as always, is much appreciated.

Comment: Set your include path to include the directory where this header file is located in your development environment. This file is sort of a starting point of most C++ code.

Comment: I apologize for my n00bery, but could you explain exactly what you mean i.e. which include path, and what precisely do you mean by development environment?

Comment: Are you using a Makefile to compile your source or how are you compiling your project ?

Comment: I just hit run in Xcode.

Comment: Oho then the files should be there. See if you have LLVM in your Xcode https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/

Comment: @DumbCoder I have the latest version of Xcode, so if it is in there by default then I have it.  Does Xcode have the c++ SDK built in?  I would think it does, because it advertises being able to handle c++ mixed in with objective c.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're pulling Objective C++ into an Objective C file. If that's the case, you just need to rename the file from a `.m` file to a `.mm` file. You'll also need to rename the `main.m` file to `main.mm` to indicate to Xcode that it needs to link against the C++ standard library.